# While moving on a curvy road (assume you're sitting in a car) whose centre of curvature lies somewhere inside earth, what force acts as centripetal?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, centripetal-force

Moving on a road bulged upward (you may think of it as if an ant is moving on an orange)... Normal is acting radially upward itself on the car, then what force is acting as a centripetal force in this case for the car?

Answer (score 2):

Gravity, in this case.  At the top of the hill, the net force will be $mg - F_N$, where $F_N$ is the normal force.  This quantity will then be equal to the required magnitude for circular motion, $mv^2/r$.

As a corollary, you can use this fact to show that a car will not remain in contact with the road if it goes over a hill too fast. If $v$ is sufficiently large relative to $g$ and $r$, then you can show that to maintain circular motion you must have $F_N < 0$.  But for an object on a surface, we must have $F_N \geq 0$ (i.e., the normal force must point out of the surface, not into the surface.)  So we conclude that the car is moving too fast to stay on the road.